# CGAL: remove faces from a constrained Delaunay triangulation

Tags: triangulation, cgal

I have a constrained Delaunay Triangulation and i want to create w hole in a shape of a polygon. a hole in which there are no faces. How can i do that using CGAL ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have "no faces". However, you can have a marker in each face indicating if you consider it or not. This is what is done in [this example](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Triangulation_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_37.8.2) where you can triangulate a polygonal domain.